# Why Marlene is a better pilot than Alicia, if Alicia was a sleeper and has B cells?

Tags: blue-gender

In Blue Gender episode 19, in a mission where Marlene wasnt on Earth but in second Earth, a pilot tells Alicia she will be the support of Yuji instead of Marlene (since Marlene isnt there). And another pilot asks if Alicia is prepared to replace Marlene. Why is so? Arent former sleepers with B cells supposed to be almost super humans with close to perfect combat skills? How can Marlene be better than Alicia then?